# C++ lambda function in macro define

Tags: c++

I read code in https://github.com/baldurk/renderdoc/blob/v1.x/qrenderdoc/Code/Interface/RemoteHost.h like this:

```
// simple helper for the common case of 'we just need to run this on the replay thread'
#define INVOKE_MEMFN(function) \
  m_Ctx.Replay().AsyncInvoke([this](IReplayController *r) { function(r); });
```

Macro is called like this

```
void TextureViewer::setScrollPosition(const QPoint &pos)
{
  m_TexDisplay.xOffset = qMax(CurMaxScrollX(), (float)pos.x());
  m_TexDisplay.yOffset = qMax(CurMaxScrollY(), (float)pos.y());

  m_TexDisplay.xOffset = qMin(0.0f, m_TexDisplay.xOffset);
  m_TexDisplay.yOffset = qMin(0.0f, m_TexDisplay.yOffset);

  if(ScrollUpdateScrollbars)
  {
    ScrollUpdateScrollbars = false;

    if(ui->renderHScroll->isEnabled())
      ui->renderHScroll->setValue(qBound(0, -int(m_TexDisplay.xOffset), ui->renderHScroll->maximum()));

    if(ui->renderVScroll->isEnabled())
      ui->renderVScroll->setValue(qBound(0, -int(m_TexDisplay.yOffset), ui->renderVScroll->maximum()));

    ScrollUpdateScrollbars = true;
  }

  INVOKE_MEMFN(RT_UpdateAndDisplay);
}
```

how `IReplayController *r` pass to the marco when this function is called?

Comment: It's not. It's passed to the lambda by the `AsyncInvoke` function, or when the "replay" system calls the callback function.

Answer (score 4):

> how `IReplayController *r` pass to the marco when this function is called?

It isn't.  All the macro does is change a line in your code like

```
INVOKE_MEMFN(my_function_name)
```

to

```
m_Ctx.Replay().AsyncInvoke([this](IReplayController *r) { my_function_name(r); });
```

It is `AsyncInvoke` that is taking the lambda and it will pass the `IReplayController*` to the lambda.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but  I see the function AsyncInvoke is  void AsyncInvoke(InvokeCallback m);   AsyncInvoke how to pass the IReplayController* to the lambda.

Comment: @wangchao Somewhere inside `AsyncInvoke` there is a line like `m(Pointer_To_IReplayController);` and that is how the lambda gets the pointer.  You pass a function to `AsyncInvoke`, and `AsyncInvoke` takes care of passing the arguments to the function that it received.  This is the general use case for lambdas/functors.